# Unable to connect even after deriving and adding macro

Tags: c++, qt

I made a class in a header file.

the class declaration:

```
class myTimer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ~snipped~
```

I have a custom slot:

```
private slots:
    void mySlot();
```

and a custom signal:

```
signals:
    QString mySignal();
```

The slot simply emits `mySignal` which then returns a `QString`.

I connect a `QPushButton` with `mySlot`:

```
connect(ui->startButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
        timer, SLOT(mySlot()));
```

and `mySignal` to a LCD number:

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(mySignal()),
        ui->lcdNumber, SLOT(display(QString)));
```

Here `timer` is the object of the class I've declared. In both the connect statements I'm getting the error `unable to convert parameter to const QObject*` pointing to the object 'timer'.

I don't know why this error is occurring even though I have properly derieved from QObject adn added Q_OBJECT macro.

Comment: How did you declare `timer` exactly?

Comment: The answer to your immediate problem is provided by David Schwartz, but what you are doing still won't work as the `connect` call expects the signal to provide a `QString` - which it doesn't.  The signals carry their data as arguments, *not* return values (see a simple example: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#a-small-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connect function's first parameter is supposed to be a `const QObject*`. There's no way to convert a `myTimer` to a `const QObject *` because one of them is an object and the other is a pointer. You probably want `&timer`.

Answer (score 1):

signals can't return any value (the return value should be void)

if you want to pas a value through a signal then you should add a parameter:

```
signals:
    void mySignal(QString);
```

and then connect as:

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(mySignal(QString)),
        ui->lcdNumber, SLOT(display(QString)));
```

Comment: That built, however didn't work as intended. What I want to do is click button -> slot on myTimer activates -> starts a QTimer object present within myTimer which is connected to an LCD number. I'm trying to understand how to do this.

Comment: @HarshilSharma That is a question unrelated to the original, please post a new one.